# How to create a class with several instances and print them?

Tags: python, function, class

I'm trying to create a piece of simple code using Class for an assignment. I've created several instances of the class and now I'm trying to format them so that I can use a print function to print all of them. I keep getting lots of small errors, especially indentation errors, and I know I'm most likely formatting the instances wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code so far:

```
#Name
#Class about environmental engineering firms in Oregon.

class EnviEngrFirmsOR:                                        #Class definition. I want it to print                
  def __init__(self, name, location, specialization, hiring):  #the details of four engineering firms                        
    self.name = name                                           #in Oregon.
    self.location = location
    self.specialization = specialization
    self.hiring = hiring

  def print_firm(self):                                       
    print(f'{firm1.name} is located in {firm1.location} and {firm1.hiring} hiring.')    
                                                             #Print function. I want it to print the
                                                              #name, location, specialization, and                          
                                                              #whether or not they're hiring,
                                                              #formatted to a single line.
                        #Ex. 'David Evans and Associates, Inc. is located in Portland and is hiring.'

firm1 = EnviEngrFirmsOR()                                                                                                 
  firm1.name = 'David Evans and Associates, Inc.'             
  firm1.location = 'Portland'
  firm1.specialization = 'multidisciplinary areas'
  firm1.hiring = 'is'
```

Comment: Learn about indendation and see how to fix them yourself. It is a simple thing.

Comment: You might want to know [what a docstring is](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that should be formatted is the way you create objects, rather than assigning each attribute its value, you should do -

```
firm1 = EnviEngrFirmsOR('David Evans and Associates, Inc', 'Portland', 'multidisciplinary areas', 'is')
```

If you still want to go to your approach, you do not need to add indentation when you assign values to your attributes, so they should be -

```
firm1 = EnviEngrFirmsOR()                                                                                                 
firm1.name = 'David Evans and Associates, Inc.'             
firm1.location = 'Portland'
firm1.specialization = 'multidisciplinary areas'
firm1.hiring = 'is'
```

Also, have a look at [this](https://realpython.com/lessons/how-and-when-use-str/), it uses **str** function to 'print' the objects (or rather returns a string representation of the object), that is the better and more conventional way to go.